# Create Dynamic Array

Tags: sql, .net, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a table name `Tankdet` which has two columns `TCO` and `Tanks`.

Here is the stored procedure code to return the count of leased, owned and principle tanks:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_Dash_LeaseInformation]  
AS  
BEGIN  
 DECLARE @leased INT  
 DECLARE @owned INT
 DECLARE @principal INT
  
 SET NOCOUNT ON  
  
 SET @owned = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Tankdet WHERE ownleasetank='owned')  
 SET @leased = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Tankdet WHERE ownleasetank='leased')   
 SET @principal = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Tankdet WHERE ownleasetank='principle') 
 SELECT [Leased]=@leased,[Owned]=@owned,[Principal]=@principal 
  
    SET NOCOUNT OFF  
END
```

The table looks like this

[image]

and it returns the values like,

```
leased = 4,owned = 4,principle = 7
```

The values which is used to show the tank count in my frontend.

The problem is here I display the whole count of principle tanks and returns it to my frontend.

Now I have the problem of creating array in getting the `Principle Tank` count as separate for each `TCO`, and I have to return it as:

```
SELECT [Leased]=@leased, [Owned]=@owned, [vibe]=@vibe, [baru]=@baru,[sarath]=@sarath, [karthi]=@karthi, [nth...]=@nth.....
```

The `nth` is because the TCO values may get added in future for purpose, and the `selected` values have to return like:

> leased=4,owned=4,vibe=2,baru=3,sarath=1,karthi=1,nth= n......,

Comment: Seems like what you *really* want is a dynamic pivot.

Comment: Side note, the `sp_` prefix is reserved by Microsoft and means **S**pecial **P**rocedure. It should not be used as a prefix for user objects. [Is the sp_ prefix still a no-no?](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix)

Comment: I have also removed the [tag:oracle] tag, as this is clearly SQL Server (due to the `dbo` schema). Please don't tag random other RDBMS when asking questions.

Comment: @Larnu yes i"m looking for dynamic pivot do you have any example to solve the problem

Comment: There are literally 100's on this site: [Dynamic Pivot SQL Server](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+dynamic+pivot+sql+server)

Comment: Why do the selected values “have” to be a comma-separated list? Why can you not just do a plain old GROUP BY and display or whatever the values as a list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tables (and resultsets) have a fixed number of columns and a variable number of rows.  So simply return

```
SELECT ownleasetank, COUNT(*) TankCount
FROM Tankdet 
GROUP BY ownleasetank
```

That will return one row per `ownleasetank` value along with the count.